# How to find database location on server for a Wordpress plugin?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a custom Tour Booking plugin in WordPress that keeps records of booking transactions made on the website. There was an anomaly recently where a payment was made but no transaction information was recorded in the CMS.

We want to inspect the database directly so I used phpadmin to view the WordPress database but can't find any records or tables that relate to the plugin.

My main question is, **where is the plugin's database located on the server**?

My knowledge of WordPress plugin development is very limited. I assume each transaction is kept in a database somewhere on the server or is that not how plugins work? Is there a particular file in the plugin directory that I should be looking at or that I need to access to reveal that information?

Let me know if any additional information is required.
Thanks in advance

Comment: you could search the db for a given string. like the transaction number etc,

Comment: I cant find any transactions when I use phpadmin to view the database. Is the plugins database located elsewhere besides where the main database resides?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It usually depends on the plugin. Some plugins are creating custom tables and are usually prefixed by the plugin name abbreviation. Some plugins are also using existing tables such `wp_posts` and save the data as a custom `post_type`. In your case, there could be a data in `wp_posts` with a `post_type` relevant to Tour Booking plugin name.. it could be a post with a `post_type` `{prefix}_booking_transactions`.

It is also possible that plugins may have used different database connection. But that would be very rare.. because that would mean the developer must know the database connection. In most cases, plugins use the main wp database.

Another case would be the plugin is using API and would save the data to a third party platform.